# Will this function consistently return dates for the upcoming and/or current weekend?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need this to return all jobs within the range for the upcoming weekend, unless we are in the weekend. Then I need it to return all jobs within the current weekend. Does this logic look sound?

```
public function index()
{
    $friday = Carbon::parse("this friday 6 pm");
    $sunday = Carbon::parse("this sunday 11:59 pm");

    if ($friday < Carbon::now()){
        $friday = Carbon::parse("last friday 6pm");
    }

    $jobs = Job::whereBetween('start_date', [$friday, $sunday])->get();
    return view('foo.bar.index', ['jobs' => $jobs]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic looks sound but you can't be sure.

To be honest this is the exact kind of thing unit tests are really good at handling. They will point out any flaws in your logic and in the event that you do get it wrong you can write regression tests to make sure it doesn't happen again.

If you can't do that for some reason then I'd extract it to a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes) and then test it out yourself using the `php artisan tinker` command.

Something like

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Job extends Model
{

    // ...

    function scopeForUpcomingWeekend(Builder $query)
    {
        $friday = Carbon::parse("this friday 6 pm");
        $sunday = Carbon::parse("this sunday 11:59 pm");

        if ($friday < Carbon::now()){
            $friday = Carbon::parse("last friday 6pm");
        }

        return $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$friday, $sunday]);
    }

    // ...

}
```

This way is more flexible, more reusable and easier to test. All you need to do at that point is run the `tinker` command. And do stuff like this:

```
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $jobs = \App\Job::forCommingWeekend()->get();
>>> $job = $jobs->first();
>>> $job->start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2012-9-5 23:26:11');
>>> $job->save();
>>> $jobs = \App\Job::forCommingWeekend()->get();
```

And just repeat until you find a way to break it.

Comment: Thanks! We are on a really tight deadline, but I have explained time and time again the importance of unit testing. I will use this as an example of why we should continue to take the time to do things correctly as opposed to quickly.